# How do I set the timezone for Google Drive from Google Apps?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

It appears that I have to proactively select the timezone I'm in to Google Drive so that they display correctly. Is there a way I can push this setting to all users within the organization?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change your timezone in the settings for Google Drive. See below screenshots.

As for changing it for all users this is not possible. Each user will have to set their timezone individually.

[image: Google Drive Settings]
[image: Google Drive Timezone]

Comment: Thanks Wade. I know that users can do this on their own but getting over 200 or more people to do it is unreasonable. Is there a management tool that would allow an admin to do so?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I've never used it, but this tool seems to indicate that it can: http://www.flashpanel.com/feature/set-calendar-time-zone/

Comment: This no longer works in the new version of Drive, can someone say what does? Haven't been able to figure that out.

Comment: @tog22: I was able to go to "Settings" => "Leave the new Drive", change the default "Time zone" and then switch back to the new Drive..

Comment: As was mentioned by @tog22 this answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to set a default timezone Google Drive and Docs Editors. A workaround is to create create a new spreasheet, set spreasheet settings as desired and use it as a template.

## Explanation

The G Suite admin could set a default timezone for user of a G Suite domain but this is only for Gmail, Google Calendar and other services but not for Google Drive and the Docs Editors. At this they don't have a global setting for the timezone.

Regarding the use of template, it's worth to say that On november 2016 Google launched a new template gallery for G Suite accounts. For details see [Create a file from a template](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/148833?hl=en).

## Reference

- [Set a time zone for new users - G Suit Administrators Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/61452?hl=en)
- [How to set default locale settings for Google Drive spreadsheets](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/TMm6ahBRkOs/Zots3LolAwAJ) (A thread of the official Google Docs Editors Help Forum)
- [Save time with new custom templates in Docs, Sheets, Slides and Forms](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/save-time-new-custom-templates-docs-sheets-slides-and-forms/) (Official Google blog)