# Change time zone globally on Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

Before the new Google Drive UI I was able to change my default timezone using the following: [How do I set the timezone for Google Drive from Google Apps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40388/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-for-google-drive-from-google-apps)

However, on the new interface I can't find the option to do it. So every spreadsheet I create I have to go and change the time zone.

I've changed the calendar timezone, but only affects the calendar, changed languages to another country and back to see if it would trigger the timezone change. It actually accepts the country I am right now as default, but it still is on the timezone of the country I've previously lived in.

Comment: What is the timezone you are now? What is the timezone of your computer? By the other hand, Google Drive doesn't only changed it's UI now Google Sheets is an independent app. (http://sheets.google.com).

Comment: UTC +10, my computer is on the correct timezone. The thing is that the option was removed from drive and I've tried to check it on Google Sheets to but could not find it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. I just posted an [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100490/88163) to the linked question that also applies to this one.